# rosbridge /rosjs/typeStringFromTopic does not work

Tags: rospy, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I call this service (/rosjs/typeStringFromTopic) with the following code:

> var types=[]; 
> con.callService('/rosjs/typeStringFromTopic', '[/mav2/fcu/mag]', function(rsp)
> {
>
> alert("here");
>
> alert(rsp);
>
> types.push(rsp);
> });

My topic is not empty but I "here" is never alerted. There is the following error in my rosbridge terminal

> Problem Problem Problem Problem Problem Problem Problem Problem Problem Problem 
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/data/my_ros/rosbridge/bin/rosbridge.py", line 39, in handleFrameHelper
> call = json.loads(frame)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 326, in loads
> return _default_decoder.decode(s)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
> obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
> raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
> Problem Problem Problem Problem Problem Problem Problem Problem Problem Problem

Thank you for your help :)

Benoît

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32194/rosbridge-/rosjs/typestringfromtopic-does-not-work/) by [BeuBeu](https://answers.ros.org/users/329/beubeu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your issue is likely how you're passing the topic argument. ros.js can take proper JSON strings or (in newer versions) pure Javascript objects, which it will convert for you. Unfortunately, your current syntax is somewhat in-between. Either:

```
 '["/mav2/fcu/mag"]'
```

or the simpler and much preferable:

```
  ["/mav2/fcu/mag"]
```

should work.

Notice how answer.ros.org's highlighting turns the first example fully green because it's a string. The second example is preferred because its harder to mess up. It's just an array containing a single string. Also remember that Javascript has two types of quotes. So:

```
  "['/mav2/fcu/mag']"
```

and:

```
  ['/mav2/fcu/mag']
```

are also fine.

This [example](http://pastebin.com/FVnjLQP0) shows reading in all of the currently published topics and displaying their types.

---

Originally posted by [tjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/502/tjay/) with karma: 461 on 2012-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0